# jQuery modal dialog prevents document events firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using some custom form elements written by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

This seems to use the `document.onmouseup` event, and other document-level events.

When used normally it all works fine.  However, when used from a modal jQuery dialog container then the document events don't seem to get fired - the modal dialog seems to prevent their propagation. It does work fine from a non-modal jQuery dialog.

So, does anyone know how to get a modal jQuery dialog to propagate certain events through to the underlying document object (or prevent then being 'cancelled', if that is what is happening).

Comment: I have the same problem, but no mind if modal or not...

Answer (score 0):

That is the definition of a modal dialog. Input events only fire for the dialog. All other components do not receive input events until the dialog is dismissed.  The alternative is to use a non-modal dialog.